# Getting error when requesting graph permissions through Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I am getting the following error stack in my app which is based on the [WebApp-graph-user  sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph). I am just trying to login and get a token for User.ReadBasic.All graph permissions.  I checked all the parameters going into AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode and it all looked good (no null values).  App is MVC web app using .net core 3.1.

stack:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.ClientCredentialWrapper.get_Thumbprint()
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.JsonWebToken+JWTHeaderWithCertificate..ctor(ClientCredentialWrapper credential, bool sendCertificate)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.JsonWebToken.EncodeHeaderToJson(ClientCredentialWrapper credential, bool sendCertificate)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.JsonWebToken.Encode(ClientCredentialWrapper credential, bool sendCertificate)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.JsonWebToken.Sign(ClientCredentialWrapper credential, bool sendCertificate)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialHelper.CreateClientCredentialBodyParameters(ICoreLogger logger, ICryptographyManager cryptographyManager, ClientCredentialWrapper clientCredential, string clientId, AuthorityEndpoints endpoints, bool sendX5C)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.OAuth2.TokenClient.SendTokenRequestAsync(IDictionary additionalBodyParameters, string scopeOverride, string tokenEndpointOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.SendTokenRequestAsync(string tokenEndpoint, IDictionary additionalBodyParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ConfidentialAuthCodeRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeParameters authorizationCodeParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context, IEnumerable scopes) in TokenAcquisition.cs
+
                var result = await application
Microsoft.Identity.Web.WebAppServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_1+<b__3>d.MoveNext() in WebAppServiceCollectionExtensions.cs
+
                    await tokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(context, options.Scope).ConfigureAwait(false);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RunAuthorizationCodeReceivedEventAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage authorizationResponse, ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties, JwtSecurityToken jwt)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()

Code:
From TokenAcquisition.cs - line 127

```
                // Do not share the access token with ASP.NET Core otherwise ASP.NET will cache it and will not send the OAuth 2.0 request in
                // case a further call to AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync in the future is required for incremental consent (getting a code requesting more scopes)
                // Share the ID Token though
                var result = await application
                    .AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes.Except(_scopesRequestedByMsal), context.ProtocolMessage.Code)
                    .ExecuteAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
                context.HandleCodeRedemption(null, result.IdToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved: This turned out to be a null client secret value due to mis-configuration as discussed here:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1476